# How to sum up in excel with different letters?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

**Consistent C or D or F**

```
NO
NO
NO
YES
NO
NO
YES
YES
```

Total { C or D or F}
How I am suppose to sum up those three letters total in one column ? Can someone help me? I know I use = Countif(B2:B9,"YES"), but It gives to total for only "yes" not "no". How can I count both letters in one column ? Is it possible or I am tripping ?

Comment: I've read your question several times and can't make any sense of it.  What are C, D, and F, and how do they relate to your example?  What is Total{C or D or F}?  How do you sum letters?  What column?  How does counting "both letters" relate to three letters or two words?  I've got to go with the "or am I tripping" as the most logical explanation for your question.

Comment: @fixer1234 I think he means count the number of times Yes occurs between a range of cells).. or count the number of times No occurs between a range of cells.  I like the 'tripping' phrase, well spotted -  when bad english is beautiful.

Comment: It looks like some people have guessed at what the question probably means.  I can't get there from what's actually written in the question.  Even if somebody comes up with the answer to whatever was asked, this question is too unclear to be use to anyone else as written.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have already figured out how to count the amount of "yes" being used, using `=Countif(B2:B9,"YES")` it is a very simple formula.

```
=Countif(B2:B9,"YES") + Countif(B2:B9,"NO")
```

If this is not what you're after, then please edit your post and clarify what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to add two more columns one for yes and one for no.

On the first column you type =if(a2="YES",1,0) and on the second one =if(a2="NO",1,0)

then at the top of the column or at the bottom you add the total of the cells.

[image: Click here to see image]